# Python function to append text in file overwrites instead

Tags: python, function

I've got a piece of code that I've since managed to get working, but don't understand why one way works and not the other.

The following code acts as though `open` mode is still `w` instead of `a`. So text inputs simply overwrite each other.

```
def new_todo(x):
    file = open("todo.txt", "a")
    file.write(x)
    return x
```

If I take the same function and remove the `return x` the append mode now works. Why is this?

```
def new_todo(x):
    file = open("todo.txt", "a")
    file.write(x)
```

Comment: They should both work in append mode. If I have to guess, you maybe put the function in a file initially using 'w' and then modifying it to 'a', but you forgot to do a reload (not an import) or restart the session, so you still have the old definition in memory?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi No error. They would both complete, but the file would have its contents overwritten or wouldn't depending on the return being present.

Comment: @user2304916 I'm using Python 2 IDLE, so I usually just hit F5 to run. Historically, that has reloaded everything fine for me.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) to understand file operations in Python

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Yeah, referenced that before the question. Didn't offer up much with respect to return in a function.

Comment: @user2304916 The issue was replicable in IDLE when adding/removing return x, but when I closed IDLE, and reopened the script, the issue stopped and now return x causes no issues with the append. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per user2304916's comment, Python 2's IDLE appeared to not be dumping the initial change of `w` mode to `a` from memory.

Exiting and reloading IDLE resolved the issue, and now the presence of `return x` does not cause text to be overwritten.

Comment: The presence of `return x` is totally irrelevant and misleading.

Comment: @user2304916 Considering that's precisely what the original question was about, it is not irrelevant at all.

Comment: The sentence "now the presence of return x does not cause text to be overwritten." is misleading. The presence of return x has never caused your problem at all.

Comment: @user2304916 Indeed it didn't, which is why this is covered in the first sentence. Most sane people would read the question before the answer, making this distinction fairly clear. If it bothers you so,  make an edit.